# Where would you go to get feedback, advice and assistance for a new theory of physics?

Tags: soft-question, relativity, quantum-gravity

I know that crackpots are constantly running down physicists to pitch them on a "new theory" that solves everything.  This has understandably led to extreme skepticism for anyone not affiliated with a university pitching a new idea.

Imagine that a loner who has spent his entire adult life educating himself on all aspects of theoretical physics comes up with a theory that approaches Relativity from a completely new perspective.

Further, imagine that theory is complex and particularly challenging to summarize because it requires rejecting some generally accepted ideas in modern physics, but it is a very lucid, rational and logical paper that really does shed new light.

Can you provide any advice as to how such a person would be able to proceed to have his paper taken seriously and reviewed or edited?

Would you hire a physics instructor, and if so, how would one go about doing that?
Is there some journal or service that would provide guidance and an editor?
Is there a board or forum for theoretical physicists willing to do consulting?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Phys.SE is about mainstream physics.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot stress enough, whoever is proposing this idea, if they are only looking to get an audience for their paper (publication) instead of feedback to learn, this is not going to go well.

If they just want to publish it to say they published it, there are many low quality journals that are very accepting with pay to publish as an avenue for this. You will not get any feedback that way, and the paper will be ignored, but it will be "published".

No matter how well intentioned, if an outsider is suggesting an idea that makes large changes to the foundations of current physics, it is likely inconsistent or doesn't match experiment.  Therefore, the most productive manner to approach this is how can one learn more about the subject at hand.  It is incredibly hard to self-assess understanding of a topic that was learned as an outsider.

So here is how I'd suggest getting critical feedback on an idea:

First consider more self study approaches. One should always approach their own work critically.

1) To better understand the foundations and also to create test theories, historically most modifications to the foundations have already been investigated.  Read up on modern treatments of current knowledge and how these ideas were tested.  Most mathematically self-consistent ideas one could come up with have already been tried.

2) Check for common issues fringe theories have.

- Does it claim a metaphysical difference (ie. this is what "really" happens even though "this appears" to be what our measurements say)?  If it doesn't give new predictions or allow one to calculate something we had to take as an assumption before (I'd consider that a kind of post-prediction), then this isn't really worth anyone's time.
- Mathematical consistency. Do predictions depend on coordinate choice? etc.
- New proposal should be stated up front and consequences should be derived from these without adding new ideas as you go.  Including math equations here and there may make the paper look more impressive to a lay person, but if the derivations don't actually flow from the stated idea, it doesn't matter.  If the paper starts defining new concepts and using a new loose analogy at every step, or arguing only be analogy with hand waving, it is not a good sign. Forcing oneself to fill in the blanks, even if it looks obvious, can help wring out issues.
- Make sure it reduces to current physical theories in appropriate limits. There is a reason Newtonian mechanics is still taught. It works incredibly well within its range of applicability.  Our current models match experimental evidence incredibly well. So a new idea can at most be a refinement. Any new theory must be able to, in the appropriate limit, reproduce the previous theories they intend to extend or supersede. If the new idea cannot do this, then it is likely already ruled out by experiment. So anyone reading a paper suggesting a key assumption is changed, will want to see explicitly how your theory reduces to current understanding in the appropriate limits.

If more self study doesn't help, then

3) They should consider taking a class at a local college if they have time.  This will help clear up most self-assessment issues, as well as introduce one to how physicists approach problems.

4) Again, with the mindset of learning, hire a gradstudent as a tutor.  Work through problems.  Many self learners think they understand a subject, but run into issues when actually trying to solve problems.

5) By now a diligent student will have learned the mistakes in their pet theory.  If not, then after 3 or 4, you'll have some physics contacts you can float an idea with.  Dumping a 46 page report on someone is a bit much. I'd suggest asking about experimental and theoretical evidence for the underpinning you are doubting. Build from there.

Comment: Truthfully... science is not something one studies at home. It's something that one does by discussing ideas in groups. That's a very quick and efficient approach to weed out nonsensical ideas right at the root. People who are afraid of that and who don't enjoy the process of being stress tested one-on-one daily are not cut out to be serious contenders for science.

Comment: Probably the best example I can think of outsiders publishing a big paper is "PRIMES is in P".  They were smart engineers, but this was publishing something outside their field. They even had to rely on a math result they didn't really understand. But the logic fit together, it was well written, and despite skepticism because they weren't part of the community, it was accepted because of merit. If it was written awfully, no one would have taken the time.  ... But as for someone who has not been in any scientific field? Yeah, I agree with you, it's really just too far of a leap.

Comment: I think one can find many great science papers that have gaping holes that are held together by giant foam hands... and they turn out to be correct or essentially correct in hindsight because their authors had the right intuition.   The thing is, though... they are usually not written by someone who has been hiding at home for their entire life to appear on the stage with the claim to revolutionize science.